# How .show() and .hide() work in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently wokring on a sign up where I hide and show different inputs depending on where they are in the sign up process.  At the moment, I have 4 inputs and I want to start off by hiding two of them.  I know in jquery you can do this with .hide().  However, when I load the page, the two inputs appear and then disappear.  What does .show() and .hide() do to the element?  Does it change the display?  How can I make it so that when the page loads the elements start off hidden and then I can call .show() when I need them?

The code I have now is below.  What I want is for me to not have to call.hide() in the ready function and for the elements to start off hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
//loads elements then hides them
  $("#input3").hide();
  $("#input4").hide();

//some time later when triggers are set and I want to show the inputs
  $("#input3").show();
  $("#input4").show();
}
```

What I want:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
//inputs 3 and 4 are already hidden

//some time later when triggers are set and I want to show the inputs
  $("#input3").show();
  $("#input4").show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add display none to your html element

```
<input type="text" id="input1" style="display: none" />
```

or with css

```
#input1, #input2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: nailed it, does .show and .hide just change the display?

Comment: Yes it is correct! See [link](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can set their initial style `display` to `none`. It is better to avoid inline styles.

**CSS**

```
#input3, #input4 {
  display: none;
}
```

In your case, your `jQuery` is handling this. Before it gets executed, your `HTML` gets parsed & hence you are able to see the `inputs` until your `JavaScript` gets executed.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

create a css like this.

```
.hide
{
display : none
}
```

and use the hide class for the div you want to hide initially.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to hide input fields using css.

```
<input type="text" name="input_name" id="input_id" />
#input_id{
display:none;
}
```

When you needs to show this input field,just call a js function like

```
$('#input_id').show()
```